# Insert data into database by linking class to btnRegister

Tags: vb.net

I am new for programming and trying to learn VB.net through youtube tutorials.

I created a windows form app for users to create new account.

I am also trying to apply the hash and salt technique to store the password for security reason.

The main issue I have is maintaining successful connection between a two class I called "DatabaseManager" and "DataHandling", codes in "btnRegister" and the database called "Test".

The program runs fine. When I click btnRegister after filling the "txtUsername.Text" and "txtPassword.Text", it gives me error that says `"Column`User_ID`does not allow nulls."`.

So this is where I keep getting issues. I tried to make it work a lot and I have no idea why it is not recording the new data. Here are my codes. I use V Studio 2012. Please help.
    Just to be clear I copied some of the codes from internet and tried to make them work with the class

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class DatabaseManager

    Private Const CONNECTION_STRING As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"

    Private connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Private usersdataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing

    Sub New()
        connection = New SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)
        usersdataadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Test", connection)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Register(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String)

        connection.Open()

        Dim usersDataset As New DataSet()
        usersdataadapter.FillSchema(usersDataset, SchemaType.Source, "Test")
        Dim table As DataTable = usersDataset.Tables("Test")

        Dim newRecord As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        newRecord("Username") = Username
        newRecord("Password") = Password
        table.Rows.Add(newRecord)

        Dim command As New SqlCommandBuilder(usersdataadapter)
        usersdataadapter.Update(usersDataset, "Test")
        usersDataset.Dispose()

        connection.Close()
    End Sub
        Public Function UsernameAvailable(ByVal username As String) As Boolean

        Dim usersDataset As New DataSet()
        usersdataadapter.FillSchema(usersDataset, SchemaType.Source, "Test")
        usersdataadapter.Fill(usersDataset, "Test")

        Dim table As DataTable = usersDataset.Tables("Test")
        For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim currnetUser As String = table.Rows(i)("Username").ToString().Trim()
            If (currnetUser = username) Then
                usersDataset.Dispose()
                connection.Close()
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        Return True
        usersDataset.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
    End Function
    Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean

        Dim usersDataset As New DataSet()
        usersdataadapter.FillSchema(usersDataset, SchemaType.Source, "Test")
        usersdataadapter.Fill(usersDataset, "Test")

        Dim table As DataTable = usersDataset.Tables("Test")
        For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim currnetUser As String = table.Rows(i)("Username").ToString().Trim()
            Dim currnetPassword As String = table.Rows(i)("Password").ToString().Trim()

            If (currnetUser = username AndAlso currnetPassword = password) Then
                usersDataset.Dispose()
                connection.Close()
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        usersDataset.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        Return False
    End Function
End Class

Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class DataHandling

    Inherits Form1
    Public Shared Function GenerateRandomString() As String
        Dim i_key As Integer
        Dim Random1 As Single
        Dim arrIndex As Int16
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim RandomLetter As String

        Dim KeyLetters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        Dim KeyNumbers As String = "0123456789"
        Dim KeyLength As Integer = 12

        Dim LettersArray = KeyLetters.ToCharArray
        Dim NumbersArray = KeyNumbers.ToCharArray

        For i_key = 1 To KeyLength
            Randomize()
            Random1 = Rnd()
            arrIndex = -1

            If (CType(Random1 * 111, Integer)) Mod 2 = 0 Then

                Do While arrIndex < 0
                    arrIndex = _
                     Convert.ToInt16(LettersArray.GetUpperBound(0) _
                     * Random1)
                Loop
                RandomLetter = LettersArray(arrIndex)

                If (CType(arrIndex * Random1 * 99, Integer)) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                    RandomLetter = LettersArray(arrIndex).ToString
                    RandomLetter = RandomLetter.ToUpper
                End If
                sb.Append(RandomLetter)
            Else
                Do While arrIndex < 0
                    arrIndex = _
                      Convert.ToInt16(NumbersArray.GetUpperBound(0) _
                      * Random1)
                Loop
                sb.Append(NumbersArray(arrIndex))
            End If
        Next

        Return sb.ToString
    End Function

    Public Shared Function CheckPassword(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal passwordHash As Byte(), ByVal salt As Byte()) As Boolean
        Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

        'Retrieve Salt String from byte array
        Dim saltStr As String = encoding.GetString(salt)
        Dim hashable As String = Trim(plainText) & Trim(saltStr)

        ' Convert into hash strings
        Dim testhash As String = EncryptStringAsHash(hashable)
        Dim realHash As String = encoding.GetString(passwordHash)

        ' Compare and return result
        Return testhash = realHash
    End Function

    Public Shared Function EncryptStringAsHash(ByVal value As String) As String
        Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
        Dim stringBytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(value)

        Dim SHhash As SHA512Managed = New SHA512Managed
        Dim hash As String = Convert.ToBase64String(SHhash.ComputeHash(stringBytes))

        Return hash
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ConvertStringToByteArray(ByVal value As String) As Byte()
        Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
        Return encoding.GetBytes(value)
    End Function
End Class

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim maxrows As Integer
    Dim incdec As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbprovider As String
    Dim dbsource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        Dim dbprovider As String
        Dim dbsource As String
        dbprovider = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbsource = "Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
        con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

        Dim dbmanager As New DatabaseManager
        Dim Data As New DataHandling

        'Generate Hash and Salt for password
        Dim salt As String = DataHandling.GenerateRandomString
        Dim hashable As String = Trim(txtPassword.Text) & Trim(salt) 'txtPassword.Text used to be password
        Dim hash As String = DataHandling.EncryptStringAsHash(hashable)

    Dim confirmationId As String = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        Dim reg As user

        reg.Username = txtUsername.Text     'txtUsername.Text used to be username
        reg.Password = DataHandling.ConvertStringToByteArray(hash)
        reg.Salt = DataHandling.ConvertStringToByteArray(salt)

        If dbmanager.UsernameAvailable(txtUsername.Text) Then

            dbmanager.Register(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)

    Dim password As String
            If txtPassword.Text = String.Empty Then
                password = "217tABCDEF42#$tolq"
            Else
                password = txtPassword.Text
            End If

            Dim salt As String = GenerateRandomString(12)
            Dim hashable As String = Trim(password) & Trim(salt)
            MsgBox("Hashable = " & hashable)
            Dim hash As String = EncryptStringAsHash(hashable)
            CheckPassword(password, ConvertStringToByteArray(hash), ConvertStringToByteArray(salt))

            frmAccessGranted.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Register, Username Already Taken!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtPassword.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did you try debug? In witch line this error happen?.what is user table schema?

Answer (score 0):

I think your User table User_id value is just missing Identity Specification option. It makes the User_id field to be generated automatically and increased by 1 (by default) for each User you add into

If you have SQL Server management studio you can put this option on:

Right click `User table -> Select "Desing" -> Select "User_id" field -> in "Column Propetries"` window put "`Indentity Specification`" option to "`Yes`" and save

Example SQL Command to create table could be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE User (User_id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL, Username NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Password NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Hi There, I am still working on the btnRegister codes to make them work as intended.  According to the codes shown below, I was able to store the Username and Password into the database. However, when the password saves, it saved the actual password that I typed and then the salt.  Obviously it is wrong to tell it to save the actual password, which is what's typed in the txtPassword.Text. I haven't changed the two classes (DatabaseManager and DataHandling). So my question is what do I have to write in place of the txtpassword.text so that the database saves hash and salt values only. Regards

Comment: Here are the codes I used.                                        Private Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
        Dim dbmanager As New DatabaseManager

        'Generate Hash and Salt for password
        Dim salt As String = DataHandling.GenerateRandomString
        Dim hashable As String = Trim(txtPassword.Text) & Trim(salt) 'txtPassword.Text used to be password
        Dim hash As String = DataHandling.EncryptStringAsHash(hashable)     dbmanager.Register(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)

Comment: One thing that you should learn when working with Visual Studio is Debugging. Click on the left edge of the code window where your code line "Dim dbmanager As New DatabaseManager" is. 

Then execute you app and when you click btnRegister your code executing stops and you Visual Studio focuses in the line put breakpoint into.

Then you can step/execute the code line by line with Shift+F8 (to step over the line) or F8 (to step into a function that is in that line).

When debugging you can hoover over the variables and see what kind of values your variables have.

Comment: My codes now work at least for registering new user. Thumbs up to all. I am now able to register the "salt and hash" version of the password and not the plaintext, which is what I wanted from the beginning. Thank you all for the help. I now have to work on the btnLogin. I want the user to be verified against the database and if the Username exists the application will grant the user access or user will be denied access and prompted to create new account. You guys have been great. Any help for btnLogin will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: The codes I used for btnRegister is what is shown below            Dim dbmanager As New DatabaseManager
        Dim data As New DataHandling

        'Generate Hash and Salt for password
        Dim salt As String = DataHandling.GenerateRandomString
        Dim hashable As String = Trim(txtPassword.Text) & Trim(salt)
        Dim hash As String = DataHandling.EncryptStringAsHash(hashable)                                  dbmanager.UsernameAvailable(txtUsername.Text)

            dbmanager.Register(txtUsername.Text, hash)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is not in the VB side, it is in the database.

You have set primary key to UserId but you are not passing any values to the userId, you are just passing values to the user name and password.

So there are two ways to solve this issues

1. you can send userid also from the VB code
2. you can just make the column UserId as autoincrement field by the following code

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1]( 
      [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       YourColumnname1 datatype,
       YourColumnname2 datatype

   )

This works only in the later versions of sqlserver 2008

```
alter table tablename 
alter column columnname 
add Identity(100,1)
```

To know more **[Click here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/)**

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the feedback. The database stores the Username and Password fine if it wasn't for the Primary Key, which I have set for the User_ID. I wanted to test it without the primary key. So I removed the primary key from the User_ID column. Then when I run the program the database saves my inputs into username and password. At least now I know that the issue is when I set the primary key. The thing is that only solved on of my issues. my other issue is the database saves the password as plaintext but it was supposed to hash and salt. Could you please use my codes, try and test them?

Comment: Hi All, I have set the "Identity Specification" to "Yes" and now the database saves the Username and Password even if the "User_ID" is set as a Primary Key.  So Bingo on that part and thank you all.  Now the major issue I have is dealing with the hash and salt part. When the password is saved, I want the plain text version of the password to go through the "DataHandling" class so that the password will be saved as a hash and salt version. Since I am eager to learn, I would kindly ask anyone to copy my codes into your machine and test it. Please make the hash and salt work and post it. Thanks.

Comment: Also I looked at as many tutorials as I can and I could never understand how the hash and salt class gets successfully connected to the btnRegister event holder. I copied some of the codes from online and paste them under the btnRegister. So as you can see, I commented out some of them even if they shouldn't be commented out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create object inside the DatabaseManager for DataHandling so it can be used. Create object like this "Dim Object as new DataHandling " after that you can use the public functions of the Datahandling from the DatabaseManager.